# When exporting FBX from Blender (for Coohom) my mesh/material gets messed up

Tags: export, .fbx

So my blender file should be fine, because my render looks beautiful. But for Coohom i can only use GLB or FBX file. When exporting it distorts kinda?
Also: I did UV-unwrap my circle so i dont understand why the stripes are back by the exporting?
In blender:
[image]
and in fbx on a 3D view website:
[image: the lines in my material]
the lines in my material

[image]
and the distortion
Please let me know if I need to add anything else for help. (Also sorry about my English, it's not my native language.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Hi. It does have the textures tho, everything is just distorted. thank you tho! I will try this when i get home

Comment: Hi so this doesn't help. Even when no textures are used my meshes (like the golden things) get these weird lines in the holes